# OpenDJ: implementations of load balancing and High Availability

Tags: load-balancing, high-availability, opendj

What would be the easiest and simplest way to provide load balancing and High Availability to a OpenDJ cluster ?

Is there some solution specific to OpenDJ, for instance a plugin, or only generic solutions (such as HAProxy) can be used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardware load balancers (or software appliances) are usually typically put in front of OpenDJ clusters for load-balancing and HA. Preferably one that has full support of LDAP, but TCP level LBs work as well.
The next version of OpenDJ (due end of 2016) should provide a Directory Proxy Server that will provide load-balancing and failover, delivering better HA for LDAP applications and directory services.